# llvm zerofill section in segment other than __DATA on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, assembly, llvm, x86-64, macos-catalina

I have a forth system that can produce self modifying code.

Currently, I have put the place where the forth words and assembly is created in the __DATA segment, and consequently, I need to mark the entire __DATA segment with rwx permissions.

Ideally, I create a new segment that will host just the forth definitions/code.

I was hoping I could do something like

```
        .section __FORTHWORDS, __bss
        .zerofill __FORTHWORDS, _bss, user_defs_start, USER_DEFS_BYTES
```

but clang complains with

```sh
error: The usage of .zerofill is restricted to sections of ZEROFILL type. Use .zero or .space instead.
```

Now, I could do exactly that, but then of course the executable size will needlessly increase.

I could probably also try mmaping some new memory and mark it rwx, I'm afraid Catalina will make me jump through code signing hoops to mmap such.

**So my question is** whether it's possible to write assembly to create a new segment with the zerofill attribute. something like this:

```
        .section __FORTHWORDS, __bss, zerofill
        .zerofill __FORTHWORDS, __bss, user_defs_start, USER_DEFS_BYTES
```

It looks like the toolchain has no way to specify that, the field for S_ZEROFILL in [MCSectionMachO.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift-llvm/blob/5bccd3526fd93ceb9e9de4ece0ffa2c5e26a9a02/lib/MC/MCSectionMachO.cpp) is not filled it. Is there a way (short of modifying clang) ?

Comment: Why is it ideal to put your Forth definitions in their own segment?

Comment: Well, it provides a bit of security - forth generated assembly should not execute stuff in the rest of the data segment. It's probably not a huge deal either way - this is less about providing high security as about avoiding unnecessary foot guns. In fact my current solution is just to mark the entire __DATA segment rwx.

Comment: Using `mmap` seems to be the obvious "ideal" solution, since that's what other JITs do. If Catalina is going to make you jump through hoops to allocate modifiable and executable memory regions the it should be doing so regardless of how you allocate them.

Comment: That's probably very wise since a rational (not necessary reasonable) strategy might be to lock things down uniformly.

**However**, it's unclear to me how to call mmap from assembly. The forth compiler I am porting is a statically linked assembler file with absolutely no libraries. It looks to me like MacOS Catalina does not have an actual mmap syscall. Ross, you wouldn't know for sure ?

Comment: I have no idea.  I would just link statically with whatever library defines the `mmap` function. Hopefully that will only pull in a minimal of code, not much more then what you'd have to write anyways.

Comment: `mmap` is defined in libsystem / libsystem_kernel dylib, so it's not possible to link it statically. The actual 64bit syscall mmap `0x200000c5`  is private API and Apple can change the syscall number at any point in future MacOS releases

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. I rather keep the binary small and have minimal dependencies than linking in a realtively huge and otherwise unneeded library. I believe that this is most in the Forth/Jonesforth spirit.

In general, I agree that given Apple's policy, it would not be appropriate to directly call mmap.

Comment: If you're minimal target is not MacOS 10.6 , the linker is adding libSystem anyway because that makes the Mach-O executable launch faster using modern `LC_MAIN` dyld approach. Unless you're not using linker at all, but your included code snippet suggests otherwise.

Comment: Interesting! How can I inspect the library code ? It doesn't seem to show up when using ```nm``` or ```objdump -l``` ? I'm probably just holding it wrong, would be nice to understand linking better. I link --static, so I hoped to find something like __mmap in the symbol table, but nada.